# How do I controll return type of useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I just want to change state to working or leaving. 
I've tried to use useState but it returns void type. How can I return boolean type? 
I'm beginner of typescript plz help me guys

```
import React, {useState,  useCallback} from 'react';
import MainHeader from 'components/UI/Main/MainHeader';

interface MainHeaderState {
   working: boolean,
}
const MainHeaderContainer:React.FC<MainHeaderState> = () =>{

    const [working, setWorking] = useState(false);
    const onWorking = useCallback(() => {
        return setWorking(true);
    }, [])

    const onLeaving = useCallback(() =>  {
        return setWorking(false)
    } ,[])

    return (
      <MainHeader
        working = {onWorking}
        leaving = {onLeaving}
      />
    );
}
export default MainHeaderContainer
```

Comment: Can you explain more? There is not much for us to help you. Please explain the problem in detail.

Comment: const setWorking: (value: React.SetStateAction<boolean>) => void //   I want to save true of boolean type in  `const onWorking`  but setWorking is returnning void type.... So It is happening type error to bind.

Comment: Please share the code for `<MainHeader/>`.

Comment: Ok I've posted the code

Comment: Can you check the updated answer? And let me know if it is much more clear or not. Also, next time if you want to give additional details just edit your question instead of adding it as an answer. As it is misleading for some viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `return` keyword.

Try this out:-

```
import React, {useState,  useCallback} from 'react';
import MainHeader from 'components/UI/Main/MainHeader';

const MainHeaderContainer:React.FC = props =>{

    const [working, setWorking] = useState(false);
    const onWorking = useCallback(() => {
        setWorking(true);
    }, [])

    const onLeaving = useCallback(() =>  {
        setWorking(false)
    } ,[])

    return (
      <MainHeader
        working = {onWorking}
        leaving = {onLeaving}
      />
    );
}
export default MainHeaderContainer
```

The MainHeader component:-

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './MainHeader.module.scss';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'components/UI/Button'

interface MainHeaderProps {
  working:() => void;
  leaving:() => void;
}
const MainHeader: React.FC<MainHeaderProps> = props => {
  return (
    <div className = {classes.HeaderWrapper}>
      <div className = {classes.Search}>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search...."/>
      </div>
      <div className = {classes.Navbar}>
        <nav>
        <span><NavLink exact to = '/notice'>notice</NavLink></span>
        </nav>
        <Button btnType = 'working' clicked = {props.working} btnValue = "working"/>
        <Button btnType = 'leaving' clicked = {props.leaving} btnValue = "leaving"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MainHeader;
```

The problem is that your prop types for `MainHeader` do not match the values that you are passing it. You are passing it a function and it was expecting a boolean (Check your `MainHeader` component). So I simply changed the prop types to function and it should work now.

Comment: Jesus..... wow Thanks very much :) I can sleep very well because of you

Answer (score 0):

- This is MainHeader component

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './MainHeader.module.scss';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'components/UI/Button'

interface MainHeaderProps {
  working: boolean,
  leaving: boolean
}
const MainHeader: React.FC<MainHeaderProps> = (working,leaving) => {
  return (
    <div className = {classes.HeaderWrapper}>
      <div className = {classes.Search}>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search...."/>
      </div>
      <div className = {classes.Navbar}>
        <nav>
        <span><NavLink exact to = '/notice'>notice</NavLink></span>
        </nav>
        <Button btnType = 'working' clicked = {working} btnValue = "working"/>
        <Button btnType = 'leaving' clicked = {leaving} btnValue = "leaving"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MainHeader;
```

Comment: I would suggest removing this answer and adding it to the question itself.